# RTK query. how to use providesTags by mutation query?

Tags: rtk-query

I'm use rtk-query first time.

I'm have only mutation endpoints. How use providesTags in post query?

I tried using providesTags for mutation directly, but it didn't help.
I tried passing body to the query endpoint, that didn't help either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

providesTags does not work on mutation. It only works with query. If you want your query endpoint to behave like mutations (for example, triggering it after a condition is met (e.g. clicking a button), you can use the skipToken. Documentation here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching